# Using 2 hard drives as one, how to create lvm/raid and /boot/efi partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, raid, lvm

Hello
I have one hdd and an ssd that I intend on using as cloud storage. When I go through the live server set up, I cannot seem to create a Software RAID or LVM along with /boot/efi. Hardware raid doesnt seem to even register with the installer. Does anyone know how to mount two drives to act as one storage system? This differs from my experiences with dual drives.

Comment: You probably don't want this. SSD and HDD have wildly differing characteristics, and commonly sizes. What you *could* do is to use the ssd as cache, in for instance a zfs configuration.

Comment: RAID is not the solution you're looking for here. An LVM could work but, if you want to specify the purpose of each storage device (SSD for the OS and applications, HDD for archives/data), then the simplest solution would be to mount the HDD to a location, like `/data`.

Comment: @Matigo I am setting up cloud storage, I'd like them to be treated as one volume, larger HDD are cheaper, my thoughts were to have older storage kept in the hdd, or just to use the entire storage space.

Comment: @vidarlo I know SSD/HDD has its draw backs, I pieced this together from spare parts, will upgrade down the line. As it the server is a dedicated cloud, I need to have the software utilize both drives. I am new to linux, have not dealt with the configs or LVM other than what I've attempted. How would utilizing the ssd as cache be of use? It's 500gb and that seems to be sort of wasteful.